# how to give validation to text box and multi select drop down in form

Tags: jquery, django

I want to submit form when multi select is selected or input is not empty. One of them must have value.

```
<form action="">

<input id="id_keywordName" type="text" value="{{keyword}}" title="Type keyword name"></input>

<select id="id_selectedKeyword" name="id_selectedKeyword" multiple title="Can select multiple Keywords">
 {%  for id,keywords in keyword_dict.iteritems %}
 {% if keywords in  keyword_list %}     
 <option value="{{keywords}}" selected>{{keywords}}</option>        
{% else %}
<option value="{{keywords}}">{{keywords}}</option>
{% endif %}
 {% endfor %}

<button type="submit" id="tcgFormsave" name="Bulkeditbtn_id" title="Click to save form">Submit</button>
</select>    
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#tcgFormsave').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        if ($('#id_selectedKeyword option:selected') || $('#id_keywordName').val()) {
            $(this).closest('form').submit();
        }
    });
```

Also you have an error in markup: your submit button is inside the selector.